# Pandas how to calculate mean for second level multi index columns

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas, How to get mean for second level columns?

```
        bar                 baz                 foo          
        one       two       one       two       one       two

aaa       1         2         3         4         5         6
bbb      -1        -2        -3        -4        -5        -6
```

Expected:

```
             one       two

aaa            3         4
bbb           -3        -4
```

Comment: `df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).mean()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameters `level=1` and `axis=1` for MultiIndex in columns:

```
df = df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).mean()
```